# Where can I edit a Google Maps shared list created on mobile?

Tags: google-maps

I created a shared list on mobile (in the Android app) for planning a trip, but for some reason, I can't find it when I use Maps from the browser among the other lists. (I'm pretty sure that this is not a sync issue, as I can use the list's share link to view it in a desktop browser, but I can't add new places to it.)

Is there a way to edit those lists somehow?

Comment: Have you already look at https://support.google.com/maps?

Comment: @Rubén I did. Similar questions on their community forum (like https://support.google.com/maps/thread/11694034?hl=en) were not answered at all.

Comment: Have you read/tried [Create a list of places](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7280933?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0)?

Comment: @Rubén Yes, but that does not cover this kind of shared list.